# Render dropdownlist in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Below is my Controller that outputs a List to Partial view. My Question is how do I render the ActionResult output as a dropdown. ( I do not want to use ViewBag Please )

```
    using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CMS.Controllers
{
    public class ArticleTypeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ArticleType
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Get(int _siteId)
        {
            using (var ctx = new CMSEntities())
            {
                List<articleType> listArticleType = CMS.Models.Cms.getArticleTypes(CMS.Models.Cms.getSiteId()).ToList();
                List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (var item in listArticleType)
                {
                    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.id.Value.ToString(), Text = item.name });
                }
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "--Select--", Selected=true  });
                return PartialView(items);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View looks like below:

```
@model List<SelectListItem>

<h2>test</h2>
```

Comment: What does your View look like?

Comment: Is there any specific issue here? Everything seems to be pretty straightforward - have a view strongly typed with list and use dropdown helper.

Comment: @howcheng I have added what currently sits in View.

Comment: @Andrei I am not sure how to use DropDownListFor ( I am new to MVC)

Comment: I suggest you start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a model property to which you're trying to bind the selected value, you can pass a lambda expression to indicate the property that you want to bind and the framework will generate the appropriate name:

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.FinancialYearID, MySelectList,
                   "Select option", new { @class= "foo" ,data-somename="dataName"})
```

your partial view should have only this dropdown and you can render this partial view any where you want using following Jquery function

```
renderPartialInDiv("partial view url","div id or class")
```

Comment: What needs to go on View top, currently i have      @model List<SelectListItem>?

Comment: you will need to send list listArticleType object to view

Comment: you can do it even without actually creating partial view just render your controller action method using rendenPartialInDiv()

Comment: Thats fine but what needs to go on top of the view?